# Undefined al invocar función con parámetros

Tags: javascript, funciones, parámetros

Hola tengo el siguiente código que me ejecuta un case dependiendo del string que se le pase a la función,pero me arroja undefined al intentar mostrar resultado por consola.

Este es el código un saludo .

```js
function calculadora(operacion, x, y) {

  switch (operacion) {

    case 'sumar':
      x + y
      break;

    case 'restar':
      x - y
      break;

    case 'multiplicar':
      x * y
      break;

    case 'dividir':
      x / y
      break;

    case 'resto':
      x % y
      break;

    case 'expo':
      x ** y
      break;
  }
}

Console.log(calculadora('sumar', 10, 20));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta **poner `return`** en las operaciones de los `case` y usar `console` con `c` minúscula.

Considera también **agregar un bloque `default` a los `case`** para poder manejar adecuadamente solicitudes de operaciones que no estén contempladas.

Además, considera **controlar la división por cero**, mediante un ternario que verifique si el divisor es o no mayor que cero.

```js
function calculadora(operacion, x, y) {

  switch (operacion) {

    case 'sumar':
      return x + y
      break;

    case 'restar':
      return x - y
      break;

    case 'multiplicar':
      return x * y
      break;

    case 'dividir':
      return y>0 ? x / y : 'No division by zero';
      break;

    case 'resto':
      return x % y
      break;

    case 'expo':
      return x ** y
      break;
      
    default:
      return 'Operación no válida';
      break;
  }
}

console.log(calculadora('sumar', 10, 20));
console.log(calculadora('expo', 10, 20));
console.log(calculadora('dividir', 10, 0));
console.log(calculadora('dividir', 10, 2));
console.log(calculadora('sumarrr', 10, 20));
```

Comment: Genial cenado eres un crack tío muchas gracias estoy empezando esto de usar ciclos y funciones y estoy súper verde muchas gracias por tu tiempo y tu. Atención

Comment: Si quisiera poner una cadena de texto acompaña del resultado como lo haría? Estoy probando a poner return ' la suma es ' , x+y
break ;

Comment: @Allan para agregar una cadena puedes hacer algo así: `return 'La suma es: ' + parseInt(x + y)` El problema es que al meter una cadena ya JS no te trarará la operación como un número y tendrás que hacer una conversión (parse) adecuada. Si no quieres *parsear* podrías devolver desde la función un array / objeto con el valor y un mensaje según cada caso y mostrarlo. Eso ya depende del uso final que quieras darle al resultado de la función. Por ejemplo si necesitaras el valor para otras operaciones, devolverlo mezclado con un mensaje te impidiría usarlo como tal (como valor independiente).

Answer (score 0):

Falta añadir que retorne la operación usando `return`, pero también puedes llamar la función `calculadora()` y dentro imprimir el resultado de la operación.

```js
function calculadora(operacion, x, y) {

  switch (operacion) {

    case 'sumar':
      console.log(x + y);
      break;

    case 'restar':
      console.log(x - y);
      break;

    case 'multiplicar':
      console.log(x * y);
      break;

    case 'dividir':
      console.log(x / y);
      break;

    case 'resto':
      console.log(x % y);
      break;

    case 'expo':
      console.log(x ** y);
      break;
  }
}

//console.log(calculadora('sumar', 10, 20));
calculadora('sumar', 10, 20)
```

Para imprimir la operación sin utilizar console.log, puedes realizar lo siguiente:

```js
    function calculadora(operacion, x, y) { 
     var resultado = "";    
      switch (operacion) {

        case 'sumar':
          resultado = (x + y);
          break;

        case 'restar':
          resultado = (x - y);
          break;

        case 'multiplicar':
          resultado = (x * y);
          break;

        case 'dividir':
          resultado = (x / y);
          break;

        case 'resto':
          resultado = (x % y);
          break;

        case 'expo':
          resultado = (x ** y);
          break;
      }      
      console.log('La operación ' + operacion + ' es: ' +  resultado);
    }


    calculadora('sumar', 10, 20);
    calculadora('restar', 10, 20);
    calculadora('multiplicar', 10, 20);
    calculadora('dividir', 10, 20);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias , ahy alguna forma de poner.    ' La suma es'  x + y.  sin utilizar console.log?

Comment: @Allan pues imprime dentro la operación y mandas llamar la operación que deseas, revisa la actualización, saludos.